# how to disable the button glow when clicked android

Tags: android, uiview, android-widget

I am trying to implement the disabling of the button glow when clicked in android. I hope this is not a lost cause. Is there a way of actually implementing this? Would appreciate a helping hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First create normal_button.xml in res/drawable folder.
In normal_button.xml write the code given below. 
Then set the normal_button.xml as a Background for the button from the properties.

`
```

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
    <item  >
    <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
</selector>

`

Answer (score 2):

Use this one

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    yourbtnobject.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);    
}
```

and in value folder make a file name color  and  write this

```
<resources>
      <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
      <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
      <color name="green">#00C000</color>          
</resources>
```

and on btn click which color you want to chose.

Comment: trivedi unfortunately, Mohits version is more practical. Yours works but I prefer tha latter. Thanks anyway.